# nuGet Package - The remote name could not be resolved: 'az320820.vo.msecnd.net' / The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway

Tags: nuget

I have re-installed the whole operating system & Windows 7 & Windows 8 R2 Server along with VS.net 2013.

Everything working fine except NuGet Packages (Latest or Download).

I do try to resolve that issue, but no success.

There are following assumption or issues.

- **Tried Options-A**
  GET http://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/packages/castle.core.3.3.0.nupkg HTTP/1.0
  User-Agent: NuGet Core/2.7.40911.287 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1)
  Host: az320820.vo.msecnd.net
- **Tried Options-B**
  DNS Lookup for "az320820.vo.msecnd.net" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
- **Tried Options-C**
  14:10:46:7695 No HTTP request was received from (chrome:480) new client socket, port 25175.
  14:10:55:0099 nt> Warning: ClientHello record was 508 bytes long. Some servers have problems with ClientHello's greater than 255 bytes. https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/Long-Handshake-Intolerance
  14:10:56:1200 No HTTP request was received from (chrome:480) new client socket, port 25176.
- **Tried Options-D**
  Event I have modified, hosts file under \System32\Driver\etc\hosts (file) : 65.52.233.252 www.nuget.org
- **Tried Options-E**
  Refer attached file: Getting data 
  Refer Screen Shot for HTTP Request 
  [image: screenshot]

Comment: I've tried everything to resolve this. For me, it's a problem with the CDN nuget is using and no route being available from the network at our office (our current provider is Grid4).

As soon as I tried to install packages from my home ISP, it worked instantly. DNS Lookups resolve for me at least, but no route seems to exist to the IP it resolves to for my work connection.

Comment: Having this same issue :(

Comment: I am on the nuget.org team. We no longer use "az320820.vo.msecdn.net". We currently use "globalcdn.nuget.org" for manual package download links. In general users should not hard-code these URLs and depends on the API endpoint:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Castle.Core/3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem is old but still someone might search for it.
On windows 10: Open Network and Sharing Center, go to your Internet/Ethernet Status and then click on Properties.

Now navigate to IPv6 and then click on Advanced. Now go to DNS tab.

Here select the option Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes, and tick the Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix.

Doing that resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

(copied from my comment)

I am on the nuget.org team. We no longer use "az320820.vo.msecdn.net". We currently use "globalcdn.nuget.org" for manual package download links. In general users should not hard-code these URLs and depend on the API endpoint: https://nuget.org/api/v2/package/Castle.Core/3.3.0

Or, use the package content API documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/package-base-address-resource#download-package-content-nupkg

The latter package content API has better availability and is the preferred route these days.

If you are having connectivity issues with nuget.org endpoints, please feel free to contact us at support@nuget.org.